# Client Side Alerts not working

Tags: javascript, meteor

```
I am using MeteorJS technology and trying alerts on success or failure
of meteor call. And alerts not working, unable to recognize the 
problem. And this is a client-side code.

             Template.socialIntFBGoogle.events({
                 'click .socialFb': function(event) {
                     Meteor.loginWithFacebook({}, function(err){
                         if (err) {
                          throw new Meteor.Error("Facebook login failed");
                          }else{
                          alert("Google login");
                          Meteor.call('transfer',function(error, result){
                          if(error){alert(error);} 
                          else{alert("Successful");}                         
                          });

                     FlowRouter.go('/');
                   }
                });
              },
           });

Thanks in Advance!
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `alert` on server side?

Comment: As an aside, purely a matter of style, why do people do this: `else{}`? If the block is empty just leave the `else` off entirely.

Comment: @nnnnnn I've never seen anyone do that, I think in this case it was just because of copying code to SO. If anyone **does** do that I agree with you, just leave it out.

Comment: @George - I've seen it in production code. I've also seen empty `if` blocks with non-empty `else` blocks. (But even for SO it would've been as easy to delete the whole thing as delete the contents of the block.)

Comment: Most likely, you're trying to use `alert` on server side. Please replace `alert` with `console.log` and see whether you get the log on Browser console (means Client side) or Terminal (means Server side). `console.log` is valid on both client and server side.

Comment: The error log quoted in the question is clearly a server side log.

Comment: Yes it is a server side alert. I have replaced it with console.log and of-course it is not throwing errors though. But question is even though I am trying alert on client side. I am not getting any alert message , and I am unable to recognize why?

Comment: @Rashmi — Since your attempts are resulting in the server throwing an error message the reason is that when you tried to write client side code, you missed and wrote it in the server side code instead.

Comment: Now I did it like this :-  if(existingAddressCheck){console.log("Google login");}else{//some code} , and it is not throwing any error @cmd. At client side My piece of code looks like this : Meteor.call('transferUserDataFromServicesToProfile', "facebook", (error, result) => {
              if(error){
               console.log(error); //If there is any error, will get error here
              }else{
               alert("Transfer of User Data From Services To Profile Successful!");
              }
             }); But still this alert not working.

Answer (score 0):

For logging purposes you should not using alert instead replace your alert calls with:

```
console.log("your message");
```

After that you can review, the output in your Web browser Dev tools.